# Storing file from dictionary in Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I've been working on a project and I'm facing a weird problem. So in my project I'm making a dictionary of data of user uploaded files and then sending the Json stringify data to Django backend. But at the end I'm getting this error:

`'dict' object has no attribute '_committed'`.

Below is my full code:

JS:

```
var file = [];
var files = {};
var jsonarr = [];
var arr = [];

file.push($('#lecturefile').prop('files')[0]);
for(var i = 0; i < file.length; i++){

    files = {
             'lastMod'    : file[i].lastModified,
             'lastModDate': file[i].lastModifiedDate,
             'name'       : file[i].name,
             'size'       : file[i].size,
             'type'       : file[i].type,
                  }
    arr.push(files)
    } 
    for(i=0;i<content.length;i++){
        jsonarr.push({'content': content[i], 'lecture': lecttitle, 'files': arr})
    }
$('#coursecont').val(JSON.stringify(jsonarr))
```

views.py

```
coursecont = request.POST.get('coursecont')
l = json.loads(coursecont)
for i in range(len(l)):
    for j in range(len(l[i]['files'])):
        con = CourseContent.objects.latest('id')
        lecture = CourseLecture(file = l[i]['files'][j])
        lecture.save()
```

I know that uploading file data like this is causing the problem but do anyone knows a work around?

Comment: in Django, uploaded files can be found in ***`request.FILES`***

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I know and I've tried that but then i get this error: `unhashable type: 'dict'`